# Xcode 10 View Controller Scene Positioning Problem

Tags: xcode, xcode10

I have inserted a label into my View Controller and centred it to the middle. When I run the app on the simulator for iPhone 6 the label is not centred.

I have tried adding constraints to the label. When running the app in the iPhone 6 simulator hides the label completely. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

- Make the background color of the label to a darker shade.
- If there are any red constraints, try to eliminate them
- The best method to centre a label is to select the label from the structure hierarchy, click on to the Align button in the bottom, select Horizontally and Vertically in Container to be at 0 value